# $f\colon \mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ Knaster-Tarski Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, order-theory

Knaster-Tarski Theorem says that for a function $f\colon L\to L$, where $L$ is a complete lattice, and $f$ is a increasing function, then a $f$ has a fixed point.

Question:

For a function $f\colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, which is defined by $f(x)= x+b$, where $b\neq 0$. $f$ does not have a fixed point, which appears a contradiction to the Knaster-Tarski Theorem.

Where am I missing?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

The fact that $\Bbb R$ is not a complete lattice since a complete lattice must have minimum and maximum. It is worth noting that in this context increasing means $x\leq f(x)$; rather than $x\leq y\rightarrow f(x)\leq f(y)$.

On the other hand, any function $f\colon[0,1]\to[0,1]$ such that $x\leq f(x)$, has a fixed point (e.g. $1$ has to be a fixed point under this condition).

Comment: @Thanks, so if I say $f: \mathbb{R}\cup{\infty} \mapsto \mathbb{R}\cup{\infty}$.. It holds. And it has at least 2 fix points, they are $+/-{\infty,\infty}$, right ?

Comment: Assuming you mean $\cup$, yes. Because of $\infty$ itself.

Comment: Thank you, but following your example $f:= 0.5x+0.01$ with dom $[0,1]$ does not hold ..

Comment: $f(1)<1$, so the conditions for the theorem fail.

Comment: No, "increasing" in the Knaster-Tarski theorem means $x \leq y \to f(x) \leq f(y)$. $f(x) = 0.5x + 0.01$ with domain $[0,1]$ has a fixpoint and that fact is implied by the Knaster-Tarski theorem.